# Exam class: Header on odd pages - including first - footer on all

Tags: header-footer, exam

How do I get my header to appear on only the odd pages, including the first one, and my footer to appear on all pages? I'm using the `exam` and I have a title with `\maketitle`.  I've tried various things. Currently my code looks like this

```
\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\lhead[O]{\makebox[.5\textwidth][l]{Name:\enspace\hrulefill}}
\rhead[O]{\makebox[.25\textwidth]{Date:\enspace\hrulefill}}
\footrule
\lfoot{Test 1: Ch 1.5 through 3.4}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{Page \thepage\ of \numpages}
```

But that's printing header and footer on all pages except the first one. I did not understand any of the hacks I found on the web.

Comment: Easier for people to help if you provide a complete(!) but [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)): it is hard to know what class or packaages you are using and some of them might have an effect on headers and footers.  As for skipping the even header, is this a one- or two-sided document?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `\oddeven` command.  That command takes two arguments; the first is used on odd numbered pages and the second is used on even numbered pages.  Thus, you'd use something like

```
  \newcommand{\myleft}{\makebox[.5\textwidth][l]{Name:\enspace\hrulefill}}
  \newcommand{\myright}{\makebox[.25\textwidth][r]{Date:\enspace\hrulefill}}
  \header{\oddeven{\myleft}{\hfill}}
         {\hfill}
         {\oddeven{\myright}{\hfill}}
```

Edit: Actually, all those `\hfill`'s are unnecessary; you can just use

```
\newcommand{\myleft}{\makebox[.5\textwidth]{Name:\enspace\hrulefill}}
\newcommand{\myright}{\makebox[.25\textwidth]{Date:\enspace\hrulefill}}
\header{\oddeven{\myleft}{}}
       {}
       {\oddeven{\myright}{}}
```

Edit: Here are two complete LaTeX files, both of which work when I test them.  The first uses `\lhead`, `\rhead`, etc., and the second uses `\header`.

```
\documentclass{exam}

\newcommand{\myleft}{\makebox[.5\textwidth]{Name:\enspace\hrulefill}}
\newcommand{\myright}{\makebox[.25\textwidth]{Date:\enspace\hrulefill}}

\lhead{\oddeven{\myleft}{}}
\rhead{\oddeven{\myright}{}}

\footrule
\lfoot{Test 1: Ch 1.5 through 3.4}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{Page \thepage\ of \numpages}

\begin{document}

Here's the first page.
\newpage

Here's the second page.
\newpage

Here's the third page.
\newpage

Here's the fourth page.
\newpage

\end{document}
```

Here's the second LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass{exam}

\newcommand{\myleft}{\makebox[.5\textwidth]{Name:\enspace\hrulefill}}
\newcommand{\myright}{\makebox[.25\textwidth]{Date:\enspace\hrulefill}}
\header{\oddeven{\myleft}{}}
       {}
       {\oddeven{\myright}{}}

\footrule

\footer{Test 1: Ch 1.5 through 3.4}
       {}
       {Page \thepage\ of \numpages}

\begin{document}

Here's the first page.
\newpage

Here's the second page.
\newpage

Here's the third page.
\newpage

Here's the fourth page.
\newpage

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: That got the header to print on only the odd pages, except the first one. How do I force the header on the first page?

Comment: @jeff It works when I test it.  Are you sure you used \header, and not \runningheader?  \runningheader would affect all pages except the first.

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice your reply till now (sorry). I'm using `lhead{\oddeven{\myleft}{\hfill}}`, and `rhead...`. Is that the problem?

Comment: @jeff That should work, but in your original question you have the optional argument `[0]` in the command `\lhead`, which won't work, since that optional argument is used for page 1.  If you're sure to omit the optional argument in both `\lhead` and `\rhead`, it should work.  You an also just use the command `\header` as in my answer.

Comment: I don't have the `[0]` in `\lhead` and `\rhead` anymore. But still nothing on first page. I also tried using `\header`, as in your example. Also, note that I am using `\footrule, \lfoot, \cfoot` and `\rfoot`. Maybe that's interfering?

Comment: I just did a test while commenting out the footer settings. They are not interfering. Still nothing on the first page.

Comment: @jeff OK, I just edited my answer to include complete latex files (two of them) that work when I test them.

Comment: The problem is `\maketitle'. When I add a title to your documents, the first page no longer gets the Name field. I guess I should have narrowed down what was causing the problem.

Comment: @jeff If you want to use the `\maketitle` command, you should immediately follow it with `\thispagestyle{headandfoot}`, since the `\maketitle` command changes the page style of that page to `plain`.  Putting in the `\thispagestyle{headandfoot}` will change it back to `headandfoot`, which is the default for the exam class.

Comment: I tried `\thispagestyle{headandfoot}' before. But I was probably using it in the wrong order. Works now.